# Copying data from var to DataTable after LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable

I am using LINQ query to filter data from a datatable and placing the data in to another datatable. For this I am using foreach statement to copy values from var to datatable. The datatable will be containing a very huge no. of rows so can you suggest me a way in which I can do the copying in a single go?

```
            var drdatedisp = from row in dtfullreport.AsEnumerable()
                             group row by row.Field<string>("Order_Date") into g
                             select new
                             {
                                 Order_Date = g.Key,
                                 totalQnty = g.Sum(a => a.Field<int>("Item_Quantity")),
                                 totalTax = g.Sum(a => float.Parse(a.Field<decimal>("TAXAMT").ToString())),
                                 totalAmt = g.Sum(a => float.Parse(a.Field<decimal>("VALAMT").ToString()))
                             };
            DataTable dtdatedisp = new DataTable();
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Order_Date");
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("Item_Quantity");
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("TAXAMT");
            dtdatedisp.Columns.Add("VALAMT");
            dtdatedisp.Rows.Clear();
            foreach (var g in drdatedisp)
            {
                DataRow newRow1 = dtdatedisp.NewRow();
                newRow1[0] = g.Order_Date;
                newRow1[1] = g.totalQnty;
                newRow1[2] = String.Format("{0:0.00}", g.totalTax);
                newRow1[3] = String.Format("{0:0.00}", g.totalAmt);
                dtdatedisp.Rows.Add(newRow1);
            }
        }
```

please see that there will be very less no of iterations....

is there any way ?? Can you Help me ??

Answer (score 3):

There is a extension method called CopyToDataTable which is unfortunately on IEnumerable Data Row object. But with the use of following link, you can create/copy same extension method which will be called on any IEnumerable object And this would match your requirement.

[Here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx#Y105)

With this you can directly write something like this in your code

drdatedisp.CopyToDataTable();

Comment: Extention methods is the way to go !

Comment: I couldnot understand this can you please explain ??

Comment: Click the link, add the class and extension method as described in the above link and call the extension method on your drdatedisp variable

Answer (score 1):

use CopyToDataTable(); Verified the result:

```
 var results = (from myRow in myData.AsEnumerable()
                          where myRow.Field<double>("Num1") == 1
                          select myRow).CopyToDataTable(); 

            DataTable dtTemp = (DataTable)results;
            gvMain.DataSource = dtTemp;
```